# Animated arrow(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I'm using the following code to animate a div class arrow;

```
function animUp() {
    $(".arrow").animate({
        top: "0"
    }, "slow", "swing", animDown);
}

function animDown() {

    $(".arrow").animate({

        top: "40px"

    }, "slow", "swing", animUp);

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    animUp();

});
```

Which works great and animates the arrow as intended. I've then added the class 'arrow' to another div with an arrow in to animate and they both stop animate down, long pause, animate up, long pause, animate down etc. Rather than the smooth animation of one arrow.

I've also tried having arrow and arrow2 and combining them in the script like this;

```
function animUp() {
    $(".arrow, .arrow2").animate({
        top: "0"
    }, "slow", "swing", animDown);
}

function animDown() {

    $(".arrow, .arrow2").animate({

        top: "40px"

    }, "slow", "swing", animUp);

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    animUp();

});
```

With the same result as above. What else can I try to get them both animating smoothly?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pnnq/) - My html structure is using bootstrap

Comment: There's lots of markup missing from this post.  I would suggest making a jsFiddle or it'll probably get closed.

Answer (score 0):

animations are added to a queue by default in jQuery to avoid queueing you should do the following:

```
function animUp() {
    $(".arrow, .arrow2").animate({
        top: "0"
    }, {
        duration: "slow",
        queue: false,
        easing: "swing",
        complete: animDown
    });
}

function animDown() {

    $(".arrow, .arrow2").animate({

        top: "40px"

    }, {
        duration: "slow",
        queue: false,
        easing: "swing",
        complete: animDown
    });

}
```

notice how instead of just passing in "slow" we now use an object

the following is from the jQuery site :: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

queue (default: true)

Type: Boolean or String

A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string. When a custom queue name is used the animation does not automatically start; you must call .dequeue("queuename") to start it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I replaced my code with yours, but the arrows don't move at all. I've tried doing a jsFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/6pnnq/ ) based on my original code, but this also doesn't animate now.

Comment: Thanks. I've used your updated code and the arrows animated down once than stopped (rather than looping up and down). I changed the second complete to animUp which kind of works, but after about 4 up and downs it goes really jerky, then stops and Coda comes to a halt.

Comment: yeah it seems to be running an infinite loop since we are skipping the queue

Comment: I will keep playing with the code, as it loops, then jerks to a halt and causes Coda to become un-responsive.